# When was the quantization of spin discovered?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, particle-physics

When was the fact that a spin could only have values S = n/2 derived? I cannot find any source that says when.

Comment: @Spencer That does not have anything to do with the history of spin.

Comment: @Spencer Please note that questions on other sites cannot be the target of a duplication on Stack Exchange sites. If you think this question does not belong on this site, you can flag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Quantization of spin was discovered experimentaly by Stern and Gerlach in 1922.
See Wikipedia article "Stern-Gerlach experiment". The correct theoretical model for spin was constructed by Pauli and Dirac in 1928.

Comment: Although a shout-out to Samuel Goudsmit might also be in order for proposing intrinsic electron spin, not just atomic spin, in 1925 (published in Nature in 1926).